# How long can you store a mixture of old bread in a no-oxygen-container?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime

I watched a TV-program where they made a mixture of old breads. It has no water in it so it is mainly carbohydrates. They used it to fry up such as chicken and fish.

**How long can you store such a mixture?**

Comment: Bread has *plenty* of water. Do you mean bread *crumbs*, which are typically used in batters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about bread crumbs--you use these to bread the outside of anything you'd want to fry up (i.e. chicken breasts).

If you stored this in a sealed container and kept this in a cool place, I would say a few months, at least.  It's possible that something like this would last for over a year or longer without going moldy.

After a few months, I would just give it a close visual inspection and taste a small amount.  Are the bread crumbs moldy?  Are they stale?  Do they still have any flavor (if there was any to begin with)?  If it passes all these tests, I'd use it.  Even if it's stale, I may still try to make a small batch of food with it because baking and frying heats water out of foods anyways.

**Side note:**  My parents have some ground spices in their kitchen from **over a decade** ago.  The spices haven't gone moldy and I don't get sick eating food with these spices in it.  However, the difference in **flavor** between these spices and new ones are like day and night.   When I cook there, I don't bother using their spices, but I won't complain if they use it for food served to me.

Comment: So it does not seem to be dangerous to eat such spices which are over a decade old when no moldy. It is clear that it is not good to eat them a lot. There are apparently more bad bacterias in such spices. - How much? Probably, I can see it with a 100x microscope and estimate it.

Comment: There's an upper limit to how much bacteria can be in your ground spices and bread crumbs with limited moisture.  **With that said**, you're never eating spices (or even bread crumbs) for nutritional content.  They're there for some added texture or flavor.  Ground spices **will** lose flavor over time--the  aromatic oils will evaporate off or oxidize slowly.  Bread crumbs just need to become crispy when fried and absorb moisture in ground meats (i.e. meatloaf), which they should be able to do for some time.  If you're not comfortable eating old food, by all means, throw it out though.